# Summation of the complex mumbers

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, roots-of-unity

[image]
Find the summation

[image]

[image]

In all the ways ia m stuck up after few steps . Any hints/help will be appreciated.  Sorry for posting everything in image format. thanks in advance

Comment: You can learn how to format mathjax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, a handy trick is that if you see someone else produce an expression and would like to know how, you can right-click on it and select "Show math as > TeX commands", and you will see the formatting used. You have been around long enough it is time for you to stop expecting others to put up with this.

Comment: Thank you for the help . I've posted it as a new question using math commands

Comment: You could have also just edited this question. But since you've posted a new one, I suggest deleting this one. (see the links on the lower left of your post, below the tags).